# Python getting the text by tag name

Tags: python, replace, tkinter, tags

I am making a simple text editor, and now I'm trying to make a replace function. The text the user wants to replace is highlighted green by using

```
.tag_add('select', index, end_index)
```

and then

```
.tag_config('select', background='green')
```

Now, I want to replace it by getting the index of text that has this specific tag and then replacing it by what the user has typed. So, my question is: How do I get the start and end index of text with a specific tag? The widget the text is in is the tkinter scrolledtext widget.

Answer (score 2):

```
# Assuming you have only one tag matching 'select'...
start, stop = text.tag_ranges('select')
text.delete(start, stop)
text.insert(start, <new_text>)
```